# Toggle the visibility of an element

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<a href="#" class="Menu">Menu</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Content</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Files</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>  
</ul>
```

1 - I need to toggle the visibility of the parent UL when the first anchor (class="Menu") is clicked

2 - I also need to toggle the visibility of each child UL when the anchor above it is clicked

How can I do this with JQuery?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: the toggle method might help, along with the click method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('a[href="#"]').click(function(){
        $(this).next('ul').toggle()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toggle method simply to hide/show elements using jquery

```
 $('.target').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Arun P Johny has the correct implementation for Jquery but if youre interested, this is the javascript approach

```
function functionName(){
     document.getElementById("outerList").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Your html modified

```
    <a onclick="functionName(); return false;" href="#" class="Menu">Menu</a>
    <ul id="outerList" style="visibility:hidden">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Content</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Files</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>  
    </ul>
```